# How can I avoid dependency on GLIBC_X.Y when using weak symbols

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, ld, weak-linking

While working on the signal implementation in Hurd, I have run into the following problem.

Basically, I add a new function to glibc, which is used by libpthread (those are from separate sources on Hurd). In order for the new libpthread to still work with older glibc's, I declare the new function as a weak symbol in the libpthread code. (See the patch [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-hurd/2011-05/msg00175.html).)

When libpthread is built with an older glibc, everything works as indended.
However, when the symbol is actually found in glibc at build time,
the linker emits a "VERNEED" corresponding to the new symbol's version
and running with an older glibc results in:

```
foo: ./libc.so.0.3: version `GLIBC_X.Y' not found
(required by /lib/libpthread.so.0.3)
```

where GLIBC_X.Y is the version for the newly introduced symbol.

The result I'm looking for is for the new symbol to be NULL
when glibc doesn't have it,
which is what happens when I build libpthread with an older glibc.

Any idea how to fix this?
Can I inhibit versionning for my symbol when linking libpthread?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I think I am having [a related problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39744926/how-can-i-compile-a-rust-program-so-it-doesnt-use-cxa-thread-atexit-impl)

Answer (score 1):

So I used a weak alias to a default implementation
instead of just a weak symbol compared to `NULL`,
and for some reason it turns out
the symbol version is not pulled in from glibc at link time.