# How can I compile a Rust program so it doesn't use __cxa_thread_atexit_impl?

Tags: rust, glibc

I have compiled a Rust program for `armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`, and I want it to run on a system that has glibc 2.16 installed. Unfortunately when running it I get this error:

```
./foo: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by ./foo)
```

Running `objdump -T foo` reveals that the only symbol needed from glibc 2.18 is:

```
00000000  w   DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.18  __cxa_thread_atexit_impl
```

[Rust makes `__cxa_thread_atexit_impl` a weak symbol](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/d75c84af806b27137ca3d6cfeba4eb904655a7ad/src/libstd/thread/local.rs#L361-L369) (as seen by the little `w` flag from `objdump`), however GCC is apparently stupid and even though all the *symbols* from GLIBC_2.18 are weak it still makes GLIBC_2.18 itself a strong requirement. You can see that with `readelf`:

```
$ readelf -V foo
...
Version needs section '.gnu.version_r' contains 5 entries:
 Addr: 0x0000000000001e4c  Offset: 0x001e4c  Link: 6 (.dynstr)
  000000: Version: 1  File: ld-linux-armhf.so.3  Cnt: 1
  0x0010:   Name: GLIBC_2.4  Flags: none  Version: 9
  0x0020: Version: 1  File: librt.so.1  Cnt: 1
  0x0030:   Name: GLIBC_2.4  Flags: none  Version: 5
  0x0040: Version: 1  File: libgcc_s.so.1  Cnt: 4
  0x0050:   Name: GCC_4.3.0  Flags: none  Version: 10
  0x0060:   Name: GCC_3.0  Flags: none  Version: 7
  0x0070:   Name: GCC_3.5  Flags: none  Version: 6
  0x0080:   Name: GCC_3.3.1  Flags: none  Version: 4
  0x0090: Version: 1  File: libc.so.6  Cnt: 2
  0x00a0:   Name: GLIBC_2.18  Flags: none  Version: 8
  0x00b0:   Name: GLIBC_2.4  Flags: none  Version: 3
  0x00c0: Version: 1  File: libpthread.so.0  Cnt: 1
  0x00d0:   Name: GLIBC_2.4  Flags: none  Version: 2
```

Notice that `GLIBC_2.18` says `Flags: none`. It should say `Flags: WEAK`. Fortunately I found [an amazing page where someone shows how to fix this](http://www.lightofdawn.org/wiki/wiki.cgi/NewAppsOnOldGlibc). Unfortunately it involves ***hex editing the binary***!

Take the offset of that `.gnu.version_r` table (`0x001e4c`), add the entry offset for `GLIBC_2.18` (`0x00a0`), then add an offset for the flags field of the struct at that address (`0x04`). That gives `0x001EF0`. At that address there should be two zero bytes: `0x0000`. Change them to `0x0200`.

Verify with `readelf`:

```
Version needs section '.gnu.version_r' contains 5 entries:
 Addr: 0x0000000000001e4c  Offset: 0x001e4c  Link: 6 (.dynstr)
  000000: Version: 1  File: ld-linux-armhf.so.3  Cnt: 1
  0x0010:   Name: GLIBC_2.4  Flags: none  Version: 9
  0x0020: Version: 1  File: librt.so.1  Cnt: 1
  0x0030:   Name: GLIBC_2.4  Flags: none  Version: 5
  0x0040: Version: 1  File: libgcc_s.so.1  Cnt: 4
  0x0050:   Name: GCC_4.3.0  Flags: none  Version: 10
  0x0060:   Name: GCC_3.0  Flags: none  Version: 7
  0x0070:   Name: GCC_3.5  Flags: none  Version: 6
  0x0080:   Name: GCC_3.3.1  Flags: none  Version: 4
  0x0090: Version: 1  File: libc.so.6  Cnt: 2
  0x00a0:   Name: GLIBC_2.18  Flags: WEAK   Version: 8
  0x00b0:   Name: GLIBC_2.4  Flags: none  Version: 3
  0x00c0: Version: 1  File: libpthread.so.0  Cnt: 1
  0x00d0:   Name: GLIBC_2.4  Flags: none  Version: 2
```

Success! Except it still doesn't work:

```
./foo: /lib/libc.so.6: weak version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by ./foo)
./foo: relocation error: ./foo: symbol __cxa_thread_atexit_impl, version GLIBC_2.18 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

How is the *weak* version still required?! I can't wait for glibc to die.

Is there any way to get Rust to build the program without using this symbol?

Comment: Accepting when things are terrible is the only way [they get improved](https://www.musl-libc.org/). Sorry if I offended any GNU developers.

Comment: You are intentionally offending the *very* people who can answer your question. I'll second @tumdum and suggest that you remove the counterproductive parts. As a partial answer, there *are* good reasons GLIBC works the way it does. And if you believe Musl is the answer, what exactly prevents you from using it?

Comment: `armv7-unknown-linux-muscl` isn't available as a target yet unfortunately. Also if I *can* get this to work glibc 2.4 is an old enough (2006) that requiring it isn't unreasonable and it saves space compared to muscl. If there is no way around requiring 2.18 (2013) then muscl is definitely a better option.

Comment: Spoke too soon - Rust 1.12 was released today with support for `armv7-unknown-linux-musclabihf`!

Comment: Actually, there are no binary releases for the muscl targets yet, but hopefully they will be coming soon.

Answer (score 4):

You need a Rust toolchain which was compiled for glibc 2.16 or earlier.  glibc 2.17 likely works as well because it lacks `__cxa_thread_atexit_impl`, so that it will not carry a `GLIBC_2.18` symbol version in the binary.

The use of the weak symbol in the Rust code is not particularly useful because GNU's particular version of ELF symbol versioning does not have weak symbol versions.  We might change that eventually, but right now, the best way to deal with this is to compile with a sufficiently old toolchain.

Another option is to backport the symbol into the glibc you use.  This should be a fairly isolated backport, probably consisting of these commits:

- [C++11 thread_local destructors support](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=ba384f6ed9275f3966505f2375b56d169e3dc588)
- [Avoid unconditional __call_tls_dtors calls in static linking.](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=e57b0c6100e63bfd816ae59339452eafc81f1d3a)
- [Also use l_tls_dtor_count to decide on object unload (BZ #18657)](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=90b37cac8b5a3e1548c29d91e3e0bff1014d2e5c)
- [Harden tls_dtor_list with pointer mangling [BZ #19018]](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=f586e1328681b400078c995a0bb6ad301ef73549)

(I have not attempted the backport to glibc 2.16, but as far as such things go, it does not look particularly difficult.)

Comment: Are there any thoughts you might be able to give for the toolchain's use of glib to perhaps relax the use of __cxa_thread_atexit_impl? Can the function only be used by an explicit call from the toolchain, or is there a path to end up indirectly using it?